# Mapbox change MGLAnnotation image when select pin i IOS

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

my problem is when I select an annotation in the mapbox mapview the state changed to selected and the image of the annotation for this I wrote this delegate method

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didSelect annotation: MGLAnnotation) {

        if let castAnnotation = annotation as? MyCustomPointAnnotation {
            if (!castAnnotation.willUseImage) {
                return
            }
            for mapAnn in mapView.annotations!
            {
                castAnnotation.selected = false
            if ((mapAnn.coordinate.longitude == annotation.coordinate.longitude) && (mapAnn.coordinate.latitude == annotation.coordinate.latitude))
            {
                castAnnotation.selected = true
                castAnnotation.willUseImage = true
                mapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)
                mapView.addAnnotation(castAnnotation)
            }

        }
        }

    }
```

the addAnnotation method fire this imageForAnnotation method:
 func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, imageFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationImage? {

```
    if let castAnnotation = annotation as? MyCustomPointAnnotation {
        if (!castAnnotation.willUseImage) {
            return nil;
        }
        if (!castAnnotation.selected == true) {

            var annotationImage = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationImage(withIdentifier: String(describing: annotation.coordinate))
            annotationImage = MGLAnnotationImage(image: UIImage(named: "pin_deselected")!, reuseIdentifier: String(describing: annotation.coordinate))
             annotationImage?.image = textToImage(drawText: castAnnotation.stepId, inImage: (annotationImage?.image)!, atPoint: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 5))
            return annotationImage!
        }else{
            var annotationImage = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationImage(withIdentifier: String(describing: annotation.title))
            if(annotationImage == nil) {
                annotationImage = MGLAnnotationImage(image: UIImage(named: "pin_selected")!, reuseIdentifier: String(describing: annotation.coordinate))
            }
            annotationImage?.image = textToImage(drawText: castAnnotation.stepId, inImage: (annotationImage?.image)!, atPoint: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 5))
            return annotationImage!
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

It's fire correctly the second case but the pin image doesn't change!!!!
I didn't know why??

Comment: when I remove the annotation it's work but when I update the annotation using the map view.add it's not working any help please

Comment: any help please

Comment: I believe that currently, the only way to change the image of a Mapbox annotation is to remove it and then add it back again. This fires the delegate method 'imageForAnnotation' as you have discovered. I really wish it was possible to update without first removing it.

Comment: I removed the annotation if you verify my code but the image still the same like in the deselected state if you have a way to delete the image can you explain me more